# Is the mapping "positive stochastic matrix onto its Perron-projection" continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, matrix-calculus, markov-process, invariance

I am dealing with a topological question concerning the mapping that maps a positive stochastic matrix onto its invariant distribution. I am asking myself if such a mapping is continuous (or measurable) with respect to suitable topologies ($\sigma$-fields). Let me describe the problem some more precisely.

Let $n>1$  and $S(n,+)$ be the space of (element-wise) positive (row-)stochastic matrices and let $A\in S(n,+)$.

Due to the Perron-Frobenius theorem, $\rho(A)=$1 is the unique eigenvalue on the spectral radius of $A$ with corresponding (right) eigenvector $v=v_A>0$, where $v$ is normalized, i.e. it is (row-)stochastic and hence can be viewed to be the unique $A$-invariant distribution.
Furthermore, $B:=B_A:=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}A^n=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n A^k\in S(n,+)$, where the rows of $B$ are all equal and are all stochastic (left) eigenvectors of $A$ and  $BA=AB=B$ as well as $B^2=B$.
Thus, $B$ is a projection, called the Perron-projection and can be written as $B=vw^t$, where $v,w$ are such that $Av=v$, $w^tA=w^t$ and $w^tv=1$.

I am wondering if the mapping $A\mapsto B_A$ or $A\mapsto v_A$, respectively, is continuous with respect to the topologies of coordinate-wise convergence.

In other words, do minor changes in the positive stochastic matrix only give rise to minor changes in the corresponding one-dimensional Perron-eigenspaces?

How can this problem best be regarded and approached? In particular in situations where it is not efficient to solve the identity $w^t A=w^t$ explicitly.

If it was a known problem, please let me know where it is described or solved, respectively.

Thanks in advance and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1. Your vector $v$ is $[1,\cdots,1]^T$; then, $A\rightarrow B_A$ and $A\rightarrow w$ are essentially the same functions.

Let $I$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in I\rightarrow A(t)$ be $C^{\infty}$ with values in the positive stochastic matrices. For every $t\in I$, the eigenvalue $1$ is simple and the associated left-eigenvector is defined up to a factor. Therefore, $(*)$ there is a $C^{\infty}$ function $t\in I\rightarrow w(t)\in (0,+\infty)^n$ s.t., for every $t\in I$, $w(t)^TA(t)=w(t)^T$ (note that $(*)$ is a global result).

The proof is easy. Let $t_0\in I$; here $\lambda=1\in \mathbb{Q}$ and there is a dimension $n-1$  submatrix $B(t)$ of $A(t)-\lambda I$ s.t. $\det(B(t_0))\not=0$. While $\det(B(t))\not= 0$, $w(t)$ (for instance $=(w_1(t),\cdots,w_{n-1}(t),1)$) is a rational fraction in the $(a_{ij}(t))$ and in $\lambda$, then in the $(a_{ij}(t))$. More generally, if $A(t)$ and one of its simple eigenvalue $\lambda(t)$ are $C^{\infty}$ (resp. holomorphic), then an eigenvector associated to $\lambda(t)$ is locally given by a $C^{\infty}$ (resp. holomorphic) function.

Beware, $(*)$ is no longer valid if $A(t)$ is only non-negative stochastic.

In fact, you ask about the function $A\rightarrow w$. Here we have only local results. Assume that $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and consider a small varaiation of $A$; then the spectrum of $A$ varies; in general, there does not exist a natural ordering of the eigenvalues of $A$, except when the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)$ are distinct. Hopefully, when the eigenvalues are distinct, using the induced ordering, Kato proved the local existence of holomorphic functions $A\rightarrow \lambda_i$ and $A\rightarrow w_i$ where $w_i$ is an eigenvector associated to $\lambda_i$.

Yet, if a special eigenvalue $\lambda$ can be isolated s.t. $A\rightarrow \lambda$ is continuous and simple, then we can prove (in a similar way) the existence of holomorphic functions associated to $\lambda$.

The set of positive real matrices, $M^+$, is open in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Proposition. Let $A_0\in M^+$.  There are analytic functions  $A\rightarrow \rho(A)$, $A\rightarrow v\in (0,\infty)^n$ (s.t. $Av=\rho(A)v$) that are defined in a neighborhood of $A_0$.

EDIT 2. @ K.O.T. 
 Let $w^T=[z,1],A-I=\begin{pmatrix}B&c\\l&\alpha\end{pmatrix}$ where $\det(A-I)=0$, that is $lB^{-1}c=\alpha$ and $B$ is invertible. Then $w^T(A-I)=0$ can be written $zB+l=0,zc+\alpha=0$. Finally $z=-lB^{-1}$ and then $zc+\alpha=0$ is automatically satisfied. $l$ is a part of $A$ and the entries of $B^{-1}$ are rational fractions in the $(a_{i,j})$; that implies that the $(z_j)$ are rational fractions in the $(a_{i,j})$.

Comment: Followup to the last sentence: you lose uniqueness when you drop the positivity assumption. This creates problems in familiar ways (for instance, it is the same phenomenon as the vertical tangents on the circle).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the comment. I was thinking about it some time. It seems interesting to me to perturb the matrix that way. But, unfortunately, I don't see (yet) how this helps to answer my question. Is it clear from your answer that the mapping t -> A(t) is an homeomorphism? Otherwise I would be in trouble arguing that A -> w is continuous. Further, I wonder why this result (if true) shouldn't continue to hold for primitive (eventually positive) matrices. It would be nice if you could leave me some further explanatory comment to your answer.

Comment: @ K.O.T. , the proper use of this forum is that if you are not satisfied with one answer, then you report it; otherwise, you accept the answer (you give the green chevron).

Comment: @ loup blanc, Sorry, it's not that I am not satisfied. After repeatedly reading your answer I think I got the idea behind and that , somehow, it covers my intuition that the mentioned mapping should be continuous because finding the right eigenvector is by solving some FINITE system of linear equations by only performing "continuous operations". But arguing that way seems too naive in view of your answer. Please allow one more comment/question:Can one even ask for more? What about an INFINITE (positive) stochastic matrix and its invariant distribution. Do you think/know an analog is possible?

Comment: Let $A$ be an infinite $>0$ stochastic matrix; then $\rho(A)=1$ may be a limit point of the other eigenvalues; therefore I think that if one wants to preserve $C^{\infty}$ correspondences, then we must add supplementary hypotheses. For example,  cf. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414987900196

Comment: @ loup blanc, I know it is some time ago, but may I ask an additional question concerning your answer from above?! I do not see why a non-zero determinant of the submatrix B(t) immediately implies that w(t) is a rational fraction in the corresponding eigenvalue and the matrix entries. Probably it is an easy argument from linear algebra I missed so far.